# Codeigniter loads html code when trying to load style.css or a img file

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, load

This is my first time using a php framework and I haven't found an effective solution.

I've made my page load style tag correctly using base_url() in an asset_helper file, and it seems to work fine.

generated code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/p_maricarmen/assets/css/style.css" media="screen" />
```

but it doesn't load the css file.

I have the same problem with others files like loading images with img tag.

I also have a *.htaccess* file in root directory with code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|public|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /p_maricarmen/index.php/$1 [L]
```

for the friendly url.

For more information, if put the style url in my navigator, it generate an html page with 404 error, page not founded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your .htaccess file with the below code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|public|assets|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /p_maricarmen/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The reason why your css file is not loading is that you've to specify the Rewrite Condition for the folder where your css and js files have been placed. 
You can do the same thing for your images folder.
Simply specify the images parent folder name as i've specified for the assets, and it should work as expected.

Hope this helps you...